# iOS accessing sandbox to verify receipt - certificate verify failed

Tags: ios, https, certificate, verify, receipt

Using curl in PHP, I get this output when I try to connect to the sandbox:

- About to connect() to sandbox.itunes.apple.com port 443
- Trying 17.152.19.192... * connected
- Connected to sandbox.itunes.apple.com (17.152.19.192) port 443
- successfully set certificate verify locations:
- CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
- SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
  error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
- Closing connection #0

Production works okay.

Is this a problem I can fix on my side? i.e. fix for real, not disabling CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST and/or CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER

I've checked the web and there doesn't seem to be any "solution" other than disabling SSL settings. I don't really want to do that in finished code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known problem with Apple. They can be tardy when updating certificates. For sandbox access, turn off security, for regular access, leave security on.